# Is the sentence "just to help me if I'd paint" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

So I was just listening to this song by Lana Del Rey and she goes:

> "said he'd come back every May, just to help me if I'd paint"

I can't really make sense of the "help me **if I'd paint**" part because that would be: "help me **if I would paint**"

Why is it *would*? Why is it not just "**help me if I paint**"?

Comment: I believe American English and British English differ on this point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if) says on ***if*** with ***will/would*** (as ***'d*** is clearly the verb contraction of ***would***):

> ***Will*** and ***would*** can be used in
> conditional clauses, either with the meaning of *‘being willing to do
> something’*, or to refer to later results:
>
> If Clare will meet us at the airport, it will save us a lot of time.
> (if Clare is willing to meet us)
>
> If you ***would*** all ***stop shouting***, I will try and explain the situation!

If you look up the meanings of ***would***, you'll find that it can also

> express willingness or consent ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=would%20meaning&safe=strict&biw=1559&bih=752&sxsrf=ALeKk03j-0iKZaPHsmRXIlIFLG4R2jUcNA%3A1623146158450&ei=rj6_YO37Gs2KjLsPjqawkAg&oq=%22would%22%20meani&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIFCAAQsQMyBwgAEIcCEBQyAggAMgQIABBDMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnOggIABCxAxCRAjoFCAAQkQI6BwgAELEDEEM6BggAEAcQHjoCCC46CggAELEDELEDEApQh5cCWLu5AmD8wQJoAXACeACAAdoBiAHzB5IBBTQuNC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would) also points out that

> We use ***would*** to talk about willingness in past time situations.

So your sentence could be read as

> He said he'd come back every May, just to help me *if I would be willing to paint.*